# AngularJS declaring variable with initial value in View?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to set the initial value of a variable in view? What I mean is:

```
<div> {{ myVar = 2 }} </div>
```

So that `myVar` is now set to 2, and I can access it via `$scope.myVar` as well when I want and change its value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `ngInit` directive:

```
<div ng-init="myVar = 2"> {{ myVar }} </div>
```

Your value will be initialized, and accessible via `$scope.myVar` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

To Concatenate the two variable value using delimiter/underscore(_) in HTML using AngularJS

```
<div ng-init="item_id = (variable_1 + '_' + variable_1)"></div>
```